# How to retain Form data After Incomplete Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code,
**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $NameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
    $name = Test_User_Input($_POST["name"]);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $name);
}

if (empty($_POST["contact"])) {
    $ContactErr = "Contact is required";
} else {
    $contact = Test_User_Input($_POST["contact"]);
    $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $contact);
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $EmailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = Test_User_Input($_POST["email"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $email);
}

if (empty($_POST["pan"])) {
    $PanErr = "PAN is required";
} else {
    $pan = Test_User_Input($_POST["pan"]);
    $pan = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $pan);
}

if (empty($_POST["dob"])) {
    $DobErr = "DOB is required";
} else {
    $dob = Test_User_Input($_POST["dob"]);
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $dob);
}

if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $GenderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
    $gender = Test_User_Input($_POST["gender"]);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $gender);
}



if (!empty($name) && !empty($contact) && !empty($email) && !empty($pan) && 
!empty($dob) && !empty($gender){
$query = "INSERT INTO form ( name, contact, email, pan, birthday, 
gender )VALUES ('$name' , '$contact' , '$email' , '$pan' , '$dob' , 
'$gender')";
} 
if ($insert_query) {
    echo "Form Filled";
} else {
    echo "Please Fill the form";
}


}
function Test_User_Input($Data)
{
    return $Data;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" autocomplete="off" method="post">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>Full Name:</label><span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $NameErr; ?></span>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] :' '?> ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>Contact Number:</label><span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $ContactErr; ?></span>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact Number" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contact']) ? $_POST['contact'] : '' ?> ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>Email Id:</label><span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $EmailErr; ?></span>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email id" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '' ?> ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>PAN:</label><span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $PanErr; ?></span>
                                    <input  type="text" name="pan" id="pan" placeholder="PAN Card No." class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pan']) ? $_POST['pan'] : '' ?> ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>DOB:</label><span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $DateErr; ?></span>
                                    <input  type="date" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="DOB." class="form-control-kyc" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 marB20">
                                <div class="form-group-kyc">
                                    <label>Gender:</label> <span class = "error_msg"><?php echo $GenderErr; ?></span>
                                    <select name ="gender" id = "gender" class="form-control-kyc">
                                    <option value="male"> Male </option>
                                    <option value="female"\> Female </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 marT30">
   <div class="form-group-kyc">
   <input type="submit" 
   id="submit" name = "submit" class="itg-button" value="Submit">
                                                </div>
    </form>
```

I want to Know, when the user fails to submit the form, how can I retain the form values, so user don't have to refill it.
Also if user forgets to fill one value , How to focus on that particular Field.?

**ALSO**
when the form is submitted and when I refresh The page, the form is again Refilled and data is sent again.
How can I prevent that?

One option is to redirect to another page after the submission, but again  when the user will press back button, the form data is sent again.

Is there anything here which can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retain the filled values of the fields.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo if(isset($_POST['$name'])? $_POST['name'] : ''; ) ?>">
```

To avoid the auto resubmission of the data you can check whether the submit button pressed or not, if not the form data will not be added to Database and redirect it to index.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['your-submit-button-name'])){
    //within this curly brackets add your codes
}else{
   header('Location: index.php');
   die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The error I am getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/dalrizdzdqfn/public_html/tradeiqresearch.com/risk-profile.php on line 418

Comment: Can you show me the code that you tried ? syntax error may be a code error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the values stored you can simply echo the post value back as shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '' ?>">
```

Comment: Its giving me a already filled space in place of placeholder , how to remove the space?

Comment: it shouldn't actually, $_POST['name'] : '' -> make sure the inside value is '' i.e without space

Comment: actually its not working. Heres the code <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']:''?> ">

Comment: everything looks fine just that `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control-kyc" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] :' '?> ">` just that there is an empty space at the end `? $_POST['name'] :' '?>` fix it. It should work